# How to pass api login key and transaction id in authorize.net sdk for android ?

Tags: android, payment-gateway, authorize.net, android-library

I am using Authorize.net payment gate way for My android Application. Normally Authorize.net ask for username and password by prompting a login screen so I dont want user to type merchant details so I edited authorize.net sdk and typed password directly instead of prompting screen to user for username and password.

Below I have posted the sdk code like I have did it

```
/**
     * Load the login ID and password prompt page.
     */
    public void showCredentialsPage() {


        showLoggingInDialog();
        PasswordAuthentication passAuth = PasswordAuthentication
            .createMerchantAuthentication("XXXXXXX",
                "XXXXX", deviceId);
        _merchant = Merchant.createMerchant(env, passAuth);

        new ExecuteTransactionTask().execute();
```

The problem is for website they use login key and transaction id Which they will get it from sandbox merchant account. If I give that login key and transaction id in the above code it says invalid credentials. If I give username and password directly in my code it works.

Comment: Did you get solution to this problem? I have same problem.

Comment: @AnkurRaiyani I have edited the sdk and made that working. I have hardcoded the merchant details and redirected the user to payment page instead of login page. But I have not tested it on live.

Comment: @Ruban have you got solution of your question?if yes then please provide me.

Answer (score 1):

The Authorize.Net Android SDK enables developers to create mobile Point of Sale application which are held by the merchant, and not on a customer's own mobile device.  A Login ID and Password should be used instead of storing sensitive login credentials on the device.  It also allows account owners to remotely approve and disable use of specific devices if they are ever lost or stolen.

Comment: "mobile Point of Sale application" means. Can you elaborate

Comment: A mobile point of sale device would be one own/controlled by the merchant and is used to accept payment from a customer during a face to face transaction.

Comment: Thank you very much @rhldr.  But I have edited the sdk and made that working. I have hardcoded the merchant details. But I have not tested it on live. Will it work when I move the app in google play.

Comment: It is not recommended to store the credentials on a mobile device.  Instead, you should use the login id and password.